# Read from the terminal from a disowned background process

Tags: terminal, background-process, input

Do we still have a possibility to read input from keyboard even if the application is running in background (disowned)?

Comment: This is an awfully specific question. Why are you specifying the method of solution before you even know it's possible? It sounds like you're trying to create a keylogger, which is better done at the tty or kernel level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems no, When process is put in background, stdin is dissociated of it (else it's not in background). 
But not stdout nor stderr, which can lead to confusing printing in the terminal when the background process print some messages.

Comment: My app is in background, but it waits for input commands from keyboard, and I don't know how to solve this problem. I need app which will work in background and expect inputs.

Comment: why not pass it in foreground, type what it waits, and put it back in background ?